# Stopping a program under certain conditions

Tags: c++, arduino, robotics

I am greeting you today with a program question for my project that uses light as an input for a servo on a wall. Light will enter the room and the shade will go down, and in the absence of light, the shade will recede.  I would like to make two conditions in a void loop in the arduino code only applicable one time unless the condition changes. By saying this I mean that, I want this void loop to run continually,in which i have two conditions.  And if the same condition is met twice in a row,(ie. sensor reading between 800 and 10000, like 5000 and and then at 6032),  nothing will run. If one condition is met and then the other is met afterwards, that's ok. Here's my code and any help as to what reference commands I should use or my next course of action would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Reports the frequency from the TSL230, higher number means brighter
// Part: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8940
// Article:  http://bildr.org/2011/08/tsl230r-arduino/ 

#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo1;
int TSL230_Pin = 4; //TSL230 output
int TSL230_s0 = 3; //TSL230 sensitivity setting 1
int TSL230_s1 = 2; //TSL230 sensitivity setting 2

int TSL230_samples = 30; //higher = slower but more stable and accurate

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  setupTSL230();
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
}


void loop(){

  float lightLevel = readTSL230(TSL230_samples);
  Serial.println(lightLevel);

if(lightLevel>800 && lightLevel<1000)
  {
    myservo1.attach(5);
    myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1300);delay(1000);
    myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1500);delay(5000000);  

}

else if(lightLevel<800)
{
  myservo1.attach(5);
  myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1700);delay(5000);
  myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1500);delay(5000000);
}
}

void setupTSL230(){
  pinMode(TSL230_s0, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(TSL230_s1, OUTPUT); 

  //configure sensitivity - Can set to
  //S1 LOW  | S0 HIGH: low
  //S1 HIGH | S0 LOW:  med
  //S1 HIGH | S0 HIGH: high

  digitalWrite(TSL230_s1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(TSL230_s0, HIGH);
}



float readTSL230(int samples){
//sample light, return reading in frequency
//higher number means brighter

  float start = micros();  
  int readings = 0;

  while(readings < samples){
   pulseIn(TSL230_Pin, HIGH);
   readings ++;
  }

  float length = micros() - start;
  float freq = (1000000 / (length / samples)) * 10;

  return freq;
}
```

Comment: There's no loop in the code above (as I'm writing this comment).

Answer (score 0):

First add this to your setup ...

```
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
setupTSL230();
pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
myservo1.attach(5);
```

}

Then make a new variable and add it to your if statements

```
Boolean once; // declare this with your other int variables 
if(lightLevel > 800 && lightLevel < 1000 && once==True)
  {
    myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1300);delay(1000);
    myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1500);delay(1000);
    once = False;
  }
 else if(lightLevel<800 && once == False)
  {
    myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1700);delay(5000);
    myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1500);delay(1000);
    once = True;
   }
```

Comment: Would I add once to my previous int variables as boolean once=True and boolean once=False? Or would I just generally assign it a number in my int variables as boolean once=6;

Comment: Okay i put the boolean once as my integer but now its within the bottom condition it'll run continuously, which I dont want.

Comment: No the variable once is of type Boolean, not integer. If you want to declare it as an integer, you can, just replace true and false with any two numbers you want.